# How to prevent auto expansion of hash arguments?

Tags: ruby, hash

Why does Ruby 2.3.1 auto-expand my hash argument when I don't provide an optional named argument (:to) and how do I prevent that?

```
def qsend(*args, to: nil,  **opts)
    puts "args: #{args}, opts: #{opts}"
end

qsend({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
qsend({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, to: "me")
```

Output:

```
args: [], opts: {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
args: [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}], opts: {}
```

When I remove args from the argument list, my hash is not dropped into opts in the 2nd call, but an error is raised: *"wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)"*. And when I remove opts from the argument list, my hash is not dropped into args in the 1st call - an error is being thrown again, this time: *"unknown keywords: a, b, c (ArgumentError)"*. Using args = {} instead of *args makes no difference.

The following call works (hash in 1st call will be dropped into args), but is there no better way?

```
qsend({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {})
```

I would prefer to solve the problem in the method definition.

edit: method renamed, output fixed.

Comment: Note: Calling a method `send` is probably a bad plan since it's got a very special meaning within Ruby.

Comment: Doesn't declaring `**opts` mean "please pull the last argument and call it `opts` if the last argument is a Hash"? Having only one argument probably leads inevitably to this behaviour.

Comment: You've reported the output incorrectly. It should be `args: [], opts: {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}` and `args: [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}], opts: {}`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, Cary, I changed args={} to *args in the last moment. Fixed now.
I also renamed the method name from send to qsend because of Object#send.

Comment: @tadman I thought it just meant "gather any keyword arguments that were provided but not explicitly declared and put them in a `Hash` called `opts`".